# MATLAB : Networks have common values, how to separate them in groups?

Tags: matlab

I'm working on a project and I encounter a problem when separating values.

**Explanations**: I have a matrix with a number of X column and X rows.
Typically, this is an example of a matrix where a column is a network.

a =

```
 1     2     2     1
 2     3     5    12
 0     4     6    13
 0     5     7    14
 0     6     8    15
 0     0     9    16
 0     0     0    17
 0     0     0    18
 0     0     0    19
 0     0     0    20
 0     0     0    21
 0     0     0    22
```

Each network has a number of vehicles and sometimes two or three networks have common vehicles.

**My question is**: how to separate them in different groups according to the following rules.

- If two networks have a common value, separate them in two groups,
- If two networks don't have a common value, regroup them in one group,
- By example, if one network has no common value with another, then it is added in Group 1 and not in Group 2 (according to rule 2).
  If a network has a common value with another, then it is placed in the first group which doesn't contains any network that shares a common value (according to rule 1).
- I accept the answers concerning the first rules but the goal is to have balanced groups.

I tried many things to solve this problem.

This code allows me to find common values ​​between each column :

```matlab
lastColumn = nbNetworks_5; % = 4 in my example

for i = 1 : lastColumn

    for columnIndex = 1 : lastColumn

        if lastColumn == 1 
           % do nothing.
 
        elseif columnIndex ==  lastColumn 
           % do nothing.
 
        else
            [CommonValue,posInCln1,posInCln2] = intersect(a(:,columnIndex), a(:, lastColumn))
            
            % If there is a common value
            if CommonValue ~= 0
                regroup = false;
                
            else % If there is no common value
                regroup = true;
                
            end
        end
    end
    
    % Decrease the max number of columns.
    % We start from the end to get to the beginning.
    lastColumn = lastColumn - 1
    
end
```

This is what my code do :

I compare the first column with the last then the second with the last, then the third with the last.
Then I move backward of one column..etc

I don't know how to separate and place those networks..

So here's what I'd like to get as a final result :

> *group1* has the *network1*,
>
> *group2* has the *network2* and the *network4*,
>
> *group3* has the *network3*.
>
> Number of created groups: 3

In order to do this :

> The network1 is going in the group1, --Intersect with all networks
>
> The network2 is going in the group2, --Intersect with Network3
>
> The network3 is going in the group3,
>
> The network4 is going in the group2.

Thank you for the time you're taken for my problem !

Kâan

Comment: You said that "_I have a matrix with a number of X column and X rows_", which indicates a square matrix, yet in your example it isn't square. Typo? I think it would be helpful to show which "decisions" you made in the process if defining the groups as in the expected output. On first glance, networks 1-3 all share the value `2`, so should be grouped together, no?

Comment: Yes, sorry it is X column and Y rows. No, they must be separated not grouped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a solution, but it is unfortuntely harder to understand because it is shorter.

First you define the data as it is. The matrix `a` is the one you provided. The command `size(a,2)` gives the amount of columns in `a`. Then you create a vector that will later conatin the number of each group. For now we take zeros to show we havent found the groups yet. `zeros(1,lastColumn)` will create [0 0 0 0].

```
a= [1     2     2     1
 2     3     5    12
 0     4     6    13
 0     5     7    14
 0     6     8    15
 0     0     9    16
 0     0     0    17
 0     0     0    18
 0     0     0    19
 0     0     0    20
 0     0     0    21
 0     0     0    22];

lastColumn = size(a,2); %amount of columns
group=zeros(1,lastColumn);
```

The loop frame of this is easy: We start at the first column and loop to the last column in the `for` loop. Then we start at the first group (`current_gourp = 1`) and check if the current column has any value from the current group. If it the group does have a value we check the next group and if the group doenst have the value (because the value is not there or the group is empty until now) we set the `current_group` as the value for our `current_column`. The hard part is how to check it and i will explain it below the code.

```
for current_column = 1 : lastColumn
    current_group = 1;
    while any(ismember(a(:,current_column),a(:,group==current_group)) & a(:,current_column)>0)
        current_group = current_group +1;
    end
    group(current_column) = current_group;
end


disp(['Total amount of groups: ' int2str(max(group))]);
disp(['The groups are ' int2str(group)]);

size_of_group=zeros(1,lastColumn);
for current_group=1:max(group)
    size_of_group(current_group) = sum(group==current_group);
    disp(['Group ' int2str(current_group) ' contains ' int2str(sum(group==current_group))]);
end
```

From the Matlab help you get:

> ismember(A,B) for arrays A and B returns an array of the same
>       size as A containing true where the elements of A are in B and false
>       otherwise.

So `intersect` might still work, but this seems to fit better. With `group==current_gourp` you get all columns that are in a certain group or nothing if the group has no member so far (try `group==2` befor the loop and after the loop). As both groupy may contain zeros the second part `a(:,current_column)>0` checks if the value is higher than 0. Only if both values are true, elemnt of the current column in the current group AND the value is higher than 0 the value becomes true. Around that the `any()` command checks if this is true for any of the current column which is enough to skip that group.

I hope this helps

Comment: Thank you a lot for this ! It was a while since I was stuck on this problem. It allows me to move forward in my code. Sorry but I can't upvote you cause of my reputation.
Just one more question, how can I have the number of networks in a group ? (1 for group 1, 2 for group 2 and 1 for group 3).

Comment: I added a loop for this above. You don't neet to upvote, but please accept the  solution so the question appears as solved

Comment: But how can I save this ? Because I need to divide a value "Z" by the number of networks per group. Like Z/1, Z/2 and Z/1 ? I think I have to do this in a loop..

Comment: ok i added one more line above. Now you can have a vector `size_of_group`. If you want to work with that the easiet way is as in the loop above `for current_group=1:max(group)`